# Translating urls of subpages of magento site

Tags: magento, multistore

I have a multi store site, I have created multi stores according to languages when user opens www.domain.com/en the site opens in ENGLISH when user opens www.domain.com/pt then site opens in PORTUGUESE language. Also I want that when user opens a subpage of site for ex. www.domain.com/pt/contactus then it should open www.domain.com/pt/Contate-nos.

What solution can I prefer for this?

Because if I will try to open my link then it will give me 404 error.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You have to use url rewrite management for this

Comment: You mean for every language I need to create a new Url Rewrite in "URL REWRITE MANAGEMENT"?

Comment: contactus - is it cms page?

Comment: no it is custom page.